# use .search() or regex to find elements that contain X in the ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, dynamic, salesforce

I have a group of input boxes that are dynamically built and added to the page. I can control the ID that is placed on the elements but it is wrapped in with a bunch of garbage. For example, I give it an ID of `clientTest` it will render an id of `j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest_mod`. There is a total of 7 input boxes that contain this Id but contain different endings. The first part of the ID is also dynamic so I can not hard code anything in.

An example,

```
<input type="hidden" name="j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest_lkid" id="j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest_lkid" value="000000000000000">
<input type="hidden" name="j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest_lkold" id="j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest_lkold" value="null">
<input type="hidden" name="j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest_lktp" id="j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest_lktp" value="001">
<input type="hidden" name="j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest_lspf" id="j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest_lspf" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest_lspfsub" id="j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest_lspfsub" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest_mod" id="j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest_mod" value="0">
```

How can I search through and find the input boxes that I want to target?

Comment: What are you interested in finding?  $('input[id*=theForm]') will give you a set containing all that have "theForm" within the ID as an example.

Comment: That is exactly what I was after! If you type it up as an answer I will mark as complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extending @Michael Chaney

```
// select the collection
var inputs = $("input[id*='theForm']");

// loop through each element.
$("input[id*='theForm']").each(function(ind, ele){
      $("#textPlace").append("<li>"+ $(ele).attr("id")+"</li>");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1zsj0zcc/1/